# ListView and Messagebox weird bug?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, messagebox

I have a project which uses a ListView. The user may select something from a listview (its set in details mode) - and in some cases a MessageBox appears which asks for a yes/no confirmation. The confirmation code does not modify the ListView or the selection in any way. The code is in the SelectedIndexChanged event handler.

The problem is this - when I make a selection which creates a popup - the program initially works as expected. The moment I move my mouse back to the list view however it causes the selection to be changed to the symbol underneath the mouse (without clicking) - its as if "HoverSelect" is on (when it isn't). This only happens after I've made a selection which involves a MessageBox popping up.

Thinking I broke something, I decide to write a simple test. I created a list view with hard-coded values and put in this code:

```
 private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

            listView1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
            listView1.Enabled = true;

      }
```

When I make a selection - the event is fired twice. I'm not sure if its related to my original problem or its just another coincidence.

Added: In my test example up there - the following happens:

First Selection - "Test"
Second Selection - "Test" "Test"
Third ... N - "Test" "Test"

So I think it is another aspect of my main problem. Removign the code to disable/enable the list view does not make a difference.

How do I make the MessageBox and ListView 'play nice' with each other?

Comment: Try the code without disabling the listview.

Comment: You are disabling the whole listview in the SelectedIndexChanged... why ? I guess that when you re-enable it, the listview re-initializes its selection status, raising the event again...

Comment: Still persists without the listview disabling. And I need the listview disabling code in my main program as the process which starts when the user makes a selection takes some time.

Comment: If you are going to show a modal dialog of some form, when the selection changes, then you don't need to disable and re-enable the listview, as they would not be able to interact with it anyway.

Comment: Ok, then the something else must be causing the event to be raised, I think you are going to need to post more of the code.

Comment: @JustinHarvey - I realise that. But in my main program after the confirmation there is a 2-3 second process which needs to occur and the user clicking on another selection will just break things. Either way it doesn't seem to make a difference (as my earlier comment says)

Comment: @JustinHarvey (2) - I gave you the entire code of the second test program. I wrote the test program just to be sure that nothign else is causign the event. This is why its so confusing.

Comment: @habibzare - When you say works do you mean that you're not having the problem I'm describing? The problem occurs after you make the second selection.

Answer (score 0):

Set [`ListView.HideSelection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection.aspx) to `false`.

> **`ListView.HideSelection`**: Gets or sets a value indicating whether the selected item in the control remains highlighted when the control loses focus.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. Was already false in the main program. When I changed it to false in the test program the problem persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem the other day, experiencing strange problems when performing actions which remove focus from the `ListView`. In my case, clicking a `ListViewItem` updated another part of the UI, which made the `ListView` lose focus and not be happy.

My solution was to do the following - add the following methods:

```
private bool AllowToLoseFocus = true;

private void MyListView_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!AllowToLoseFocus)
        MyListView.Focus();
}

private void MyListView_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    AllowToLoseFocus = false;
    //do stuff here
    AllowToLoseFocus = true;
}
```

Maybe not the neatest solution and may not work in your case... but worth a try!

Comment: Still not working. The 'MyListView_Leave' code isn't being triggered when the MessageBoxes are appearing. Only occurs when I manually change the focus by clicking on another winform element.

Comment: Oh, that's irritating. Sorry I couldn't help!

Answer (score 0):

i think i solve your problem:

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsSelected)
        {
            if (!e.Item.Selected)
            {
                e.Item.Selected = false;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Solves the problem on the test program. However the issue still persists on the main program.

Also your if (!e.ItemSelected) part of the code is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The SelectedIndexChanged Event fires twice because its the behaviour by design.

> When the user selects an item without pressing CTRL to perform a
>   multiple selection, the control first clears the previous selection.
>   In this case, this event occurs one time for each item that was
>   previously selected and one time for the newly selected item.

For more take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I can't reproduce your hovering-issue but you could try this to show the message box only one time (works only if you don't use multiselect)

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a quick go and reproduced it straight away, it is a tricky one.  I can show you a solution, it is not great, but it works. You need to use a second form instead on the MessageBox and go back to disabling/enabling the listview.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.Enabled)
    {
        listView1.Enabled = false;
        Form2 confirm = new Form2();
        confirm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(confirm_FormClosed);
        confirm.Show();
    }
}

void confirm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Enabled = true;
}
```